# Oracle: How can I add these constraints?

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I made three tables, "investigador", "inv_proy" and "proyecto"

```
    CREATE TABLE INVESTIGADOR (nip number, nombre varchar(20),
    apellido varchar(20), fecha_nac date, sexo char, dir varchar(20), correo varchar(50));

  CREATE TABLE PROYECTO (id number, descripcion varchar(50), duración number, fecha_inicio date, presupuesto number); 

CREATE TABLE INV_PROY (nip number, id number, fecha date, cargo varchar(20)); 


ALTER TABLE INV_PROY ADD CONSTRAINTS INV_PROY_PK PRIMARY KEY (NIP);

ALTER TABLE INVESTIGADOR ADD CONSTRAINTS INVESTIGADOR_PK PRIMARY KEY (NIP);
ALTER TABLE PROYECTO ADD CONSTRAINTS PROYECTO_PK PRIMARY KEY(ID);
```

How can I make it so each time I add a register to INV_PROY there is both an associated INVESTIGADOR and a PROYECTO register?

And how can I make it so that each time I erase a register from INVESTIGADOR it's also erased from its associate tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to answer your question without knowing how the three tables are related but the common answer is to use foreign key constraints with cascading deletes.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. I should decide what to use as foreign keys.